# What's the proper proof to show that H is a subspace of V?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $V$ be the vector space, which is defined as $$V=\left\{f \colon \mathbb{R} \to\mathbb{R} \right\}.$$ and let H be the set of functions which satisfy $f{(0)}=0$, i.e. $$H=\left\{ f\colon \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}\colon f{(0)}=0 \right\}.$$ How would one prove that H is a subspace of V? I understand that you must prove that $H$ contains the zero vector, $H$ is closed under addition, and that $H$ is closed under scalar multiplication. But how would you prove this for ALL functions? Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Hint: If $f(0)=g(0)=0$, what is $(f+g)(0)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By definition of $H$ it contains the zero vector. Consider adding two functions $g(x)$ and $h(x)$ both in $H$. So $(g+h)(0) =g(0)+h(0)= 0 + 0$ because they are in $H$. I will leave it to you to show how it works for scalar multiplication. Because $V$ defines all functions from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$ and $H$ describes just those that meet one criteria, than the functions in $H$ are a subset of those in $V$ by definition, thus $H$ is a subspace of $V$.

Comment: But shouldn't your answer be more specific? In that doesn't $g{(x)}$ need to be defined somehow?

Comment: No. You want to keep everything very unspecific. $g(x)$ is defined as any function from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$ with the property that $g(0)=0$. That is all that you need to know about it, beyond that you do not care. It can constant, i.e. $g(x)=0$, it can be discontinuous, it can be anything as long as $g(0)=0$. This way you deal with ALL of the functions with this property, which you were having a problem with understanding.

Comment: So to show that it's closed under scalar multiplication, I would say $$f{(c0)}=cf(0)=c0=0?$$

Comment: Scalar multiplication means you multiply the elements of your set by $c$, not their argument. So you would have $cf(0)=c 0 = 0$. But yes, that is almost correct.

Comment: Great, I thought I was somewhat close with this all, just missing a small link somewhere. Many thanks.

Comment: @Azovax If an answer is sufficient please accept it to close the question so that it gets removed from the "active" list.